# In a beam, when there is a UDL present on a small portion, why do we add a UDL above and below of the remaining beam?

Tags: structural-beam

[image]

In the above image, I need to find the deflection at point C and D of the simple supported beam. Macaulay's method is to be used.

To solve this, on part BC a UDL of 1 kN/m is introduced both above and below so that they neutralise each other and the net effect remains unchanged, as seen below :-

[image]

Why do we need to introduce the extra UDL? Why can't we just convert the original UDL to point load and calculate the deflection using Macaulay's method?

Comment: What does UDL stand for?

Comment: @BobD Uniformly Distributed Load

Comment: OK but why does the UDL look like a spring?

Comment: @BobD This is how it is drawn in the book.

Comment: Never saw it  depicted that way. Anyway I'm not familiar with the Macaulay method so I probably can't help here.